# Install windows or newer ubuntu from old Live CD

Tags: live-cd

I have an ubuntu 10.10 cd lying around and I want to install either ubuntu 14.04 or windows 7. Unfortunately I have no USB at the moment. Is this possible without having to go through 7 painful upgrade processes to get to 14.04?

Comment: I don't think that will work it. Its going to need some upgrade packages to install and i don't think you will be able to get them anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but you will probably need to burn a new disk. Also it would be VERY hard to do all those upgrades as upgrading from old releases is a long process as the location of the new files is updated on the ubuntu server side. You will need a new dvd or usb if you want to have anything near a stable system.